# Validating and transform the array objects in JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

Would like to have the output JSON based on the active status in the input array.If active is true provide the value object.
INPUT :

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "active": true,
      "value": "Clampable",
      "key": "40300"
    },
    {
      "active": false,
      "value": "Mixed load",
      "key": "40302"
    }
]
}
```

SPECS:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "services": {
        "*": {
          "key": {
            "40302": {
              "#mixed": "loading_method"
            },
            "40300": {
              "#clampable": "loading_method"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

OUTPUT :

```
"loading_method" : [ "clampable", "mixed"]
```

I do not want the mixed value as output as the status is false.
Any advise would be great..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works,

If active is true then, shift the value node.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "services": {
        "*": {
          "active": {
            "true": {
              "@(2,value)": "loading_method"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Jagadesh, it works. Can you please tell me how to only consider the first element in an array in JOLT SPEC....

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you be more clear. Are you asking about the first element in the result?

Comment: Yes , I used =firstElement , and it worked, Thanks a lot Jagadesh, Really appreciate your help..